# objective-c - What is a proper way to declare delegates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, delegates, synthesize

I'm new to objective-c and iOS development and in my class I'm declaring delegate protocol.

I found several examples of doing it and they all look very similar but have some differentiations that I want to make clear for myself and understand.

**Example 1:**

(links - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660523/2117550 and https://github.com/alexfish/delegate-example/blob/master/DelegateExample/CustomClass.h)

*MyClass.h*

```
#import <BlaClass/BlaClass.h>

@class MyClass; // removed in example 2
@protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) myClassDelegateMethod:(BOOL)value;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyClassDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

*MyClass.m*

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass 
@synthesize delegate; // removed in example 2

- (void) myMethodToDoStuff {
  [self.delegate myClassDelegateMethod:YES]; 
}

@end
```

**Example 2:**
(links - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm)

Actually is the same except these two differences..

### Things that differ them:

- In example 1 we declare `@class` before protocol, is it really necessary? or just best practice. Second example works fine without this declaration.
- In example 1 we use `@synthesize delegate` as I understand it makes getters/setters for the property but do we really need it? Second example works without this.

Both examples work fine I just want to remove the confusion rising in me.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a good idea to pass the source instance to the delegate. Take a look at Apples delegate implementation (like `UITableViewDelegate`) for better examples of well formed protocols.

Comment: Don't forget to check if the delegate responds to the selector before calling myClassDelegateMethod: since myClassDelegateMethod: is specified as @optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `@class MyClass` is required if the protocol methods have a reference to the class. It is common for protocol methods to provide a parameter to the class. You are not doing that in your example so it isn't needed.

The use of `@synthesize` hasn't been needed for a while. Don't use it unless you have a specific reason to use it.

Answer (score 1):

`@class` tells the compiler that a class exists before reaching its `@interface`. It's useful when two class/protocol headers would have to `#import` each other only. It's likely to be the case once you create your protocol.

`@synthesize` *used* to be necessary to create getters and setters, but now we also have so-called automatic properties. When you don't use `@synthesize`, the compiler will create an instance variable to hold the property value and will generate getters and setters anyway. `@synthesize` gives you slightly more control over the process but isn't necessary anymore.